# How to manage reset signal for VHDL testbenches?

Tags: vhdl, reset, test-bench

I have a very simple VHDL testbench that should run.

My components all have a reset signal, so that registers are set to 0 and other components correctly initialized, but if I create a common signal for resetting all component only during the first clock cycle, how can I tell to that signal to go down after the first clock cycle and never get up again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
reset <= '1', '0' after 10 ns;
```

Answer (score 0):

if more control of the length of the reset timing is needed then the following can be used

```
reset <= '1', '0' after 25 ns, '1' after 35 ns ;
```